# Watson Assistant does not accept an entity value pattern

Tags: regex, watson-assistant

I try to use the expression A and not B - for no avail. I have the value "number". when i want the bot to accept "one and two" i put the pattern (one.*)(two.*) and it  accepts. however when i want it to accept only "one" and not "two", i put the pattern (one.*)(!two.*) and it does not accept even "one". When I put the pattern (one.*)(?!two.*)is returns "invalid perl operator: (?!" Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't use lookaheads then, if you get that error message.

Comment: See the rules here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-entities#entities-patterns